# How do I format the display of a select from properties of the objects using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.StateList = {"States": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Code": "AL",
        "Name": "Alabama"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Code": "AK",
        "Name": "Alaska"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Code": "AZ",
        "Name": "Arizona"
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "Code": "AR",
        "Name": "Arkansas"
    }]}
```

And I display the data as follows in an html select:

```
 <select ng-model="Address.State" 
 ng-options="state.Code as state.Name for state in StateList.States"></select>
```

Right now this will display the full name of the state in the select like "Arizona". What I would like to do is format the display without adding a new property to the object, to use something like (state.Name, state.Code, state.Id). I am trying to use filters of some sort to do this but I have not figured it out yet. Thanks for your suggestions.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkODzf2BckbmVngwK8KJ)

Comment: Something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/bGslHVhyGXuZhGXLV5PC?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways that you can achieve this. The first is to just set the value you want inline:

```
<select ng-model="Address.State" ng-options="state.Code as (state.Name + ', ' + state.Code + ', ' + state.Id)  for state in StateList.States"></select>
```

Or you can do the same thing, but as a function in your controller:

```
$scope.display = function(state) {
    return state.Name + ', ' + state.Code + ', ' + state.Id;
}

<select ng-model="Address.State" ng-options="state.Code as display(state) for state in StateList.States"></select>
```

Or you can create a filter (as per PSLs answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a small format filter:-

```
app.filter('stateName', function() {
  return function(itm) {
    return [itm.Name , itm.Code, itm.Id].join();
}});
```

and use it as:-

```
 ng-options="state.Code as (state|stateName) for state in StateList.States
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3LvOfWv3v3BfUNo7WN5P?p=preview)**